# Generating file with ajax and allow user to download it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have very similar problem as this: [Allowing users to download files - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966972/allowing-users-to-download-files-asp-net) , but in my case I am generating xlsx file with ajax, and on ajax-called aspx page I am using:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
string filename = User.Identity.Name + "_Report.xlsx";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
Response.WriteFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports\\" + filename);
Response.End();
```

When this file is generated, control is returned to ajax calling page and from there I wan't to show save file dialog based on this ajax response and allow user to download this generated file. I don't want to save file on disk with ajax called page and then redirect ajax calling page to that file, because of popup blocker in IE. I am using jquery for ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({  
    type:"POST", 
    url: "AjaxReport.aspx",               
    data:dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        //don't want to use this  
        // $('#RedirectIFrame').attr('src','Reports/Report.xlsx?cache='+Math.random());
        //want to use data variable containing ajax response (bytes of Report file) showing
        //save dialog to download this file from browser
    }              
});
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently JavaScript can't access to the user's file system, meaning you can't prompt users to save a file coming from a network stream.

In other words. You'll need to do that redirect and write your file stream to the HTTP response and let the user decide what to do :)